# Counting multiple types of related records

Tags: mysql

Can you help me solve this MySQL problem? I have 2 tables, one for a file and another for actors, I need to know how many women and men there are per file in a query. This is trying to use a `LEFT JOIN`, but maybe there is a more efficient way.

```
SELECT  of.expediente, COUNT(ac.id) AS Hombres, COUNT(acM.id) AS Mujeres
FROM    oficialias of
LEFT JOIN  actores ac ON ac.expediente = of.expediente  AND ac.genero = 'H'
LEFT JOIN  actores acM ON acM.expediente = of.expediente  AND acM.genero = 'M'
WHERE   of.expediente = 'TECA/00003/2018'
GROUP BY  ac.genero, acM.genero
```

Comment: Solo Ingles aqui. Only English on this website.

Comment: column names not in english is ok isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your group by. You are counting the number of male and female acotrs per expediente not by gender.

```
old: group by ac.genero, acM.genero

new:  GROUP BY of.expediente
```